# Android - Извлечь значения из .xml массива

Tags: xml, android, java, массивы

Здравствуйте! Есть .xml массив, в котором каждая строка выглядит так:
<string name="sname">int1|int2|int3|int4|String1|String2</string>
В коде есть переменные, в которые нужно положить только часть xml строки, то есть вертикальная полоса как бы разделяет значения. Как это сделать?

На плюсы не скуплюсь :)

Comment: *** up ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] val = xmlString.slit("|");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] val = xmlString.slit("|");
```